# If text compairson statement failing in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been fighting with this for a while and I'm not getting why the if statement is returning true when one of the AND statements is obviously false.

```
strtmp = TypeName(ctl) 'Take for instance (and have verified) this returns String type with the value of Label. However the below is returning true in this case.
If (strtmp = "TextBox") And (arControlName(2) = "Desc") And Trim(Me.Controls(ctl.Name).Value & "") = "" Then
 'Do some stuff
End If
```

My problem is the first statement of the if is somehow equating to true OR "And" is not working as I expect "The AND = TRUE if **all** conditions are TRUE. The AND=FALSE if **any** of the conditions are FALSE." OR I'm using it wrong?

Perhaps I am simply loosing my marbles as well :)

EDIT: If the statements are broken out into 3 separate If statements (like below), the code works as expected.

```
If (strtmp = "TextBox") Then
    If (arControlName(2) = "Desc") Then
        If Trim(Me.Controls(ctl.Name).Value & "") = "" Then
         ' Set the value and exit loop
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: What is `arControlName`... an array?

Comment: @PeterT Yes.  It's a `Split(ctl.Name, "_")` In this particular case it's "lblPort1" "13" and "Desc" so that is true.  In addition to the 1st if not being true, the 3rd should error and "Resume Next" since a Label does not have a Value attribute.

Comment: @PeterT Another interesting development.  If I split them out into 3 separate if statements the code works as expected.  See the edit

Comment: Is there any reason that the *order* of evaluation could be playing a role? Hard for us to judge with the information you provide - we just don't know what all these things represent, exactly. But you might try using () around the first two tests so that they're evaluated first, before the result is compared to the third? Or test two-by-two, to see where it's "going wrong"...

Comment: @CindyMeister I don't see why order would matter with an AND statement as it should be all or nothing.  However that did give me an idea.  If I remove `And Trim(Me.Controls(ctl.Name).Value & "") = ""` from the evaluation, it works.  I've tired `If ((strtmp = "TextBox") And (arControlName(2) = "Desc")) And (Trim(Me.Controls(ctl.Name).Value & "") = "")` and it still returns the whole statement as true even thought one is false.  I've even tried making 2 to return false.  Can you not execute a function in an If statement in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the comments that got my brain jogging in a different direction, I've determined the problem.

It apparently has something to do with VBA and not liking to execute certain calls in an If Statement  It seems to work fine putting the `TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox"` in the if statement but not the call to `Me.Controls(ctl.Name).Value & ""`.

```
strctlTypeName = TypeName(ctl)
strctlVal = Trim(Me.Controls(ctl.Name).Value & "")
If ((strctlTypeName = "TextBox") And (arControlName(2) = "Desc")) And strctlVal = "" Then 'And (Trim(Me.Controls(ctl.Name).Value & "") = "") Then
 'Set the value and exit inner for loop
End If
```